# Visualize a Jena ontology model in Java

Tags: ontology, jena, visualizer

I would like to visualize an Ontology model created through Jena in Java. Is there an API which can help me out in this task ? Or at least a tutorial on the matter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JUNG API (http://jung.sourceforge.net/) to visualize the ontology as a graph.

Comment: Thanks m8, the JUNG API seems ideal for my application, so I'll try it out.

Comment: You can also check out Prefuse (http://www.prefuse.org/). I used Flare (Flex version of Prefuse) and JUNG. I would suggest you to go with JUNG as you can find more documentation/tutorials on JUNG.

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape (www.cytoscape.org/) is a great tool for graph visualization, and has been widely used by linked data repositories.

Comment: I was looking into this tool, unfortunately its plugin Rdfscape seems to be no longer available.